# Cardano Triplet transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

When I solve the [Project Euler #251](https://projecteuler.net/problem=251).
The formula 
$$ \sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt{c}} + \sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}} = 1 $$
could be transformed into 
$$ 8a^3+15a^2 + 6a -27b^2c =1 $$
But I didn't sort it out.

How to do the transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, $$\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt{c}} =1-\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}} \tag{1}$$ $$\Rightarrow a +b\sqrt{c} = 1-3\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}[1-\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}] -a +b\sqrt{c} \,\,\,\,(\text{by cubing (1)})$$ $$\Rightarrow 2a-1 =- 3\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}[1-\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}] =- 3\sqrt[3]{a-b\sqrt{c}}\sqrt[3]{a+b\sqrt{c}}\,\,\,(\text{using (1) to simplify})\tag{2}$$ $$\Rightarrow 8a^3-12a^2+6a-1 = -27(a^2-b^2c)\,\,\,\,(\text{by cubing (2)})$$ $$\Rightarrow \boxed{8a^3+15a^2+6a-27b^2c = 1}$$